# fopen(): Filename cannot be empty (laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I´m having an 
`ErrorException` in `FilesystemAdapter.php` line 146:

```
fopen(): Filename cannot be empty
```

Using laravel `FilupLoad->store()` method

the form is multipart/form-data

the store code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo') && $request->photo->isValid()) {

            // dd($request->file('photo'));
            $path = $request->photo->store('profiles');

            $imagen = new Imagen(['url' => $path]);

            $imagen->save();

            $perfil->imagen()->attach($imagen);
        }
```

If I use `dd($request->file('photo'));` y see the filename

Any help on this?
after look at the `FilesystemAdapter.php` and it seems to be a problem with `getRealPath()`, always returns false. Any ideas? I'm new to php

Comment: And line 146 is which of the 11 lines you show us?

Comment: Is part of the laravel's FilesystemAdapter. I dont think that i must change that. I'm new to php

Comment: @RiggsFolly i look at the FilesystemAdapter.php and it seems to be a problem with getRealPath(), always returns false. Thats all i can find.

Comment: you reference `getRealPath()` in your question yet don't show us where it is in the code. Plus your posted answer should only be an answer if you can say that it did not work in PHP version X yet it works in PHP Y. If you cant show those parameters then it is not a valid answer. A reason for why one version of php worked over another version would help you get upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having problems with this too, I wanted to add what I found, in case it helps somebody else.

1) Check your `php.ini` file, specifically the `; sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"` which should be able to be left commented off, atleast for `IIS` using `PHP` `v5.6`,

2) verify also the `upload_tmp_dir=C:\WINDOWS\temp` which should be set.

3) Also you need the extention for `php_fileinfo` enabled, which in windows is `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

When you test, you can debug output like this, the following should both come back `true`

`dd($request->hasFile('my_file'));`

`dd($request->file('my_file')->isValid());`

4) Check permisssions on those directories if your still having problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with Internet *Information Services (IIS) for Windows®* Server. The only thing needed is - permission for

> C:\Windows\temp

because it is set as

> upload_tmp_dir

in php.ini for php7.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i try the same code in another php installation and works. So may be something in my php.ini